# How to replace list elements and reiterate through in Python 3.9.0

Tags: python, python-3.9

Started with random correction values and trying to get them <= .01 but I don't know how to take the adjusted values and reinsert them so the program runs until it gets the value down to .01

Q1final, Q2final, and Q3final all need to be replaced by qcorr1, qcorr2, and qcorr3 but I'm not sure how to have python do this

```
def main():
    
    L = [1500, 400, 600, 800, 700, 1000, 750, 450, 550, 800, 800, 1450]
    C = [100, 100, 120, 110, 110, 90, 100, 130, 130, 130, 130, 90]
    D = [.833, .833, .833, .667, .667, .833, .833, .833, .333, .833, .833, .833]
    Qmgd = [2.77574, 3.12947, 1.4832, .83693, .35373, 1, 1.39444, .39444, .1019, 1, .35373, 2.3944]
    Q = [i * 1.54722 for i in Qmgd]
    hl = [0]*12

    Q1sign = [0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    Q1final = []
    for value1, value2 in zip(Q, Q1sign):
        Q1final.append(value1 * value2)

    Q2sign = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    Q2final = []
    for value3, value4, in zip(Q, Q2sign):
        Q2final.append(value3 * value4)

    Q3sign = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0]
    Q3final = []
    for value5, value6, in zip(Q, Q3sign):
        Q3final.append(value5 * value6)
    

    for i in range(12):
        k = 4.727 * L[i]/((C[i]**1.852) * (D[i]**4.8704))
        hl[i] = k * Q[i]**1.852
        sumhl1 = sum(hl[4:8])
        sumhl2 = (hl[1] + hl[7] + hl[9] + hl[10])
        sumhl3 = (hl[2] + hl[3] + hl[8] + hl[9])

    botterm1 = 1.852*(hl[4]/Q1final[4] + hl[5]/Q1final[5] + hl[6]/Q1final[6] + hl[7]/Q1final[7] + hl[8]/Q1final[8])
    botterm2 = 1.852*(hl[1]/Q2final[1] + hl[7]/Q2final[7] + hl[9]/Q2final[9] + hl[10]/Q2final[10])
    botterm3 = 1.852*(hl[2]/Q3final[2] + hl[3]/Q3final[3] + hl[8]/Q3final[8] + hl[9]/Q3final[9])

    qk1 = (sumhl1 / botterm1)
    qk2 = (sumhl2 / botterm2)
    qk3 = (sumhl3 / botterm3)

    qcorr1 = []
    for a in Q1final:
        if a != 0:
            qcorr1.append(a + qk1)
    print(qcorr1)
    qcorr2 = []
    for b in Q2final:
        if b != 0:
            qcorr2.append(b + qk2)
    print(qcorr2)   
    qcorr3 = []
    for c in Q3final:
        if c != 0:
            qcorr3.append(c + qk3)
    print(qcorr3)

    while qk1 > .01:
        Q1final.append(a + qk1)
        if qk1 <= .01:
            print(Q1final)

    while qk2 > .01:
        Q2final.append(b + qk2)
        if qk2 <= .01:
            print(Q2final)

    while qk3 > .01:
        Q3final.append(b + qk3)
        if qk3 <= .01:
            print(Q3final)

main()
```

The while loops are an attempt at the iteration but it won't go through, it looks like it isn't running the qcorr values through the hl[i] line

Comment: It is not clear what you need, define "*reinsert*" and "*replace*", because `qcorr1`, `qcorr2`, and `qcorr3` are smaller lists than `Q1final`, `Q2final`, and `Q3final`, so it is not possible to recalculate  `qk1`, `qk2`, and `qk3`, and this keeps the loop running forever...

Comment: @CreepyRaccoon I want it to use the corrected values at the bottom `qcorr` in place of `Qfinal` and then recalculate `qk`